# C++ Fill template array with random values

Tags: c++, arrays

How to fill a **template** array with random values? I want to fill array depending on the type (or char, or int, or double, or float), and with using template functions. And I have the error: C2297 '%': illegal, right operand has type 'T' template.

My code:

```
template <typename T>
void fillArray(T arr[], int n, T a, T b)
{
    if (is_same<T, char>::value)
    {
        T c;
        int r, aNo, bNo;
        aNo = (int)a - 97;
        bNo = (int)b - 97;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            r = rand() % (bNo - aNo + 1) + aNo;
            arr[i] = (T)r + 97;
        }
    }
    else if (is_same<T, double>::value || is_same<T, float>::value)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            T f = (T)rand() / RAND_MAX;
            arr[i] = a + f * (b - a);
        }
    }
    else if (is_same<T, int>::value)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            T f = (T) (rand() % b + a);
            arr[i] = f;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only use `%` with integers, and all the code has to be correct regardless of `T`. Look for `if constexpr` in your favourite C++ book. (Or just overload your function. Does it have to be a template?)

Comment: If the use of a template is a requirement, I'd prefer a specialization and the use of concepts (or SFINAE) over this code...

Comment: This code is impacted by C-style code :(. It is bad in any C++ code, but in case of C++ template it is very painful.

Comment: [std::generate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) and `std::generate_n` does all of this work already.  Your `fillArray` is attempting to reinvent this wheel.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U>
void uniform_fill_random(T& v, U from, U to)
{
    static std::random_device device;
    static std::mt19937 engine { device() };

    std::uniform_int_distribution<U> dist { from, to };
    std::ranges::generate(v, [&]() { return dist(device); });
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/s4W46334z

Comment: `std::random_device` doesn't need to be static, you can create a oneshot one: `static std::mt19937 engine( std::random_device{}() );`.